# Twig and truncating text

Tags: mysql, twig

I created this simple Twig page on localhost on MAMP:

```
   <html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }        
      tr.heading {      
        font-weight: bolder;
      }        
      td {
        border: 0.5px solid black;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
      }    
    </style>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Automobiles</h2>
    <table>
      <tr class="heading">
        <td>Vehicle</td>
        <td>Model</td>
        <td>Price</td>
      </tr> 
      {% for d in data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ d.manufacturer|escape }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.model|escape }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.modelinfo|raw }}</td>
      </tr> 
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the code behind it:

```
    <?php
// include and register Twig auto-loader
include 'Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

// attempt a connection
try {
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=world;host=localhost', 'root', 'mypass');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage();
}

// set error mode
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// attempt some queries
try {
  // execute SELECT query
  // store each row as an object
  $sql = "SELECT manufacturer, model, price FROM automobiles";
  $sth = $dbh->query($sql);
  while ($row = $sth->fetchObject()) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }

  // close connection, clean up
  unset($dbh); 

  // define template directory location
  $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');

  // initialize Twig environment
  $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

  // load template
  $template = $twig->loadTemplate('cars.html');

  // set template variables
  // render template
  echo $template->render(array (
    'data' => $data
  ));

} catch (Exception $e) {
  die ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

However, I am planning to truncate the text in the modelinfo field, I believe this can be done in MySQL with the select LEFT function, but how should I modify the query?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't seem to be fetching a 'modelinfo' field at all...

Answer (score 7):

You can truncate text in your Twig template like this:

```
{{ d.modelinfo[:10] }}
```

That should return the first 10 characters in `d.modelinfo`.

Take a look at the [slice filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) documentation page.

Comment: This will actually return the last 10 characters. `{{ d.modelinfo[:10] }}` will return the first 10.

Answer (score 4):

Twig has a truncate filter but you have to enable the text extensions by adding the following to your config.yml file.

```
services:
 twig.extension.text:
     class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
     tags:
         - { name: twig.extension }
```

Then in your template you can use the truncate filter and pass it an integer which denotes the length of the truncation.

```
{{ d.modelinfo|truncate(50) }}
```

Comment: Where should I put the config.yml file, since I'm not using Symfony?