# Twig and error messages - is this normal?

Tags: twig

I've been testing Twig on localhost... the code here is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817159/twig-and-truncating-text) but the query is different:

```
     <?php
// include and register Twig auto-loader
include 'Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

// attempt a connection
try {
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=world;host=localhost', 'root', 'mypass');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage();
}

// set error mode
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// attempt some queries
try {
  // execute SELECT query
  // store each row as an object
  $sql = "SELECT manufacturer, model, modelinfo FROM automobiles WHERE id = '4' ";
  $sth = $dbh->query($sql);
  while ($row = $sth->fetchObject()) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }

  // close connection, clean up
  unset($dbh); 

  // define template directory location
  $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');

  // initialize Twig environment
  $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

  // load template
  $template = $twig->loadTemplate('cars.html');

  // set template variables
  // render template
  echo $template->render(array (
    'data' => $data
  ));

} catch (Exception $e) {
  die ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

I have 3 records; I decided to query a non-existent record to see what Twig's error handling was like, as I was comparing Twig vs Smarty - out of interest, and for a project.
This error message comes up:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: data in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/twigtesting.php on line 42
```

Surely a notice saying 'Data not found' should happen or am I wrong here?
Undefined variable data refers to:

```
      // set template variables
  // render template
  echo $template->render(array (
    'data' => $data
  ));
```

Why is this happening? I'm new to Twig, and using the latest build from their site, f that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get a Twig error, because the error does not exists in the templates, but in the code that is generating these templates.

PHP is having issues to put the value of `$data` inside an array, because that variable does not exists.

If you want to see how twig handles errors, you need to access a non existing variable inside a template. For instance, putting `{{ notExisting }}` in your current template.

---

I can already say that Twig is handling errors by throwing parsing exceptions in PHP. All exceptions thrown by Twig are extending [`Twig_Error`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/v1.4.0/Twig_Error.html). To catch these, use a `try { ... } catch (\Twig_Error $e) { ... }` block.

Furthermore, Twig can throw 3 different types of Exceptions:

- [`Twig_Error_Syntax`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/v1.4.0/Twig_Error_Syntax.html) is thrown when an error occurs when parsing a template (e.g. using malformed tags).
- [`Twig_Error_Loader`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/v1.4.0/Twig_Error_Loader.html) is thrown when Twig can't load a file. This can happen when using a `render()` method, or when you use some file features in Twig (e.g. `{% extends ... %}`).
- [`Twig_Error_RunTime`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/v1.4.0/Twig_Error_Runtime.html) is thrown when an error occurs in runtime (e.g. an error inside extensions).